# VS2010 Custom Build Tool Template

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I use many custom build tools in visual studio 2010 for generating protocol buffer code.  I'm curious if there's a way to create a template for this custom build tool so that I can just apply it to any .proto files I create?  I'm using native c++ and I know there's a plugin for the .net version to do something similar but it's not appropriate for my uses.